# Как увеличить или уменьшить массив, при этом сохранив его значения ну или уменьшив

Tags: c#, ref

```
static  void func(ref int[] array,int value)
    {   
        array = new int[value];         
    }       
    public static void Main()
    {           
        int[] myarray = new int[5] {4,8,9,3,1};//5 элем             Console.WriteLine(myarray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число,которое увелич или уменьш массив");
        int value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        func(ref myarray,value);
        
        foreach(int item in myarray)
        {       
            Console.Write(item + " ");
        }
```

Обязательно с использованием ref,
У меня код просто переписывает маасив, старый адрес удаляет, создает новый под размер массива, а как сделать чтобы он увеличил, но не терял значения, единственное что приходит на ум, это сохранить значения в другом массиве, а после пересоздания массива присвоить эти значения обратно, так можно реализовать?

Comment: что значит "увеличить массив"? Числа в этом массиве, что ли?

Comment: Так присвойте `new int[value];` в переменную с **другим именем**, потом скопируйте туда из `array` нужное число элементов, и потом уже присвойте в `array` этот новый массив.

Comment: @Эникейщик кол-во элементов, размер массива

Comment: [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Обратите внимание на предыдущий комментарий , мне кажется это правильный ответ в данной ситуации.

Comment: @CrazyElf Блин, провозился столько времени, пытался передать значения из массива в массива с помощью Copy, CopyTo, и выдавала ошибку что превыше размер массива, только благодаря for смог реализовать, спасибо вам. static  void func(ref int[] array,int value)
    {   
        int[] massiv = new int[value];
  
  for(int a = 0;a < array.Length;a++)
  {  
   massiv[a] = array[a];
  
  }
  array = massiv;

Comment: @DaniilLoban к сожалению нужно было создать свой метод Resize

Comment: @gachi_muchenik Вы только учтите, что там возможны два варианта: новый массив может быть больше исходного, а может быть и меньше, это надо учесть в цикле `for` чтобы не выйти за рамки нового массива.

Answer (score 0):

Никто вам не мешает создать новый массив, но не присваивать его сразу в переменную с текущим массивом:

```cs
static  void func(ref int[] array,int value)
{   
    var new_array = new int[value];         
    // тут нужно скопировать из array данные в new_array
    // <ваш код с копированием>
    array = new_array; // в конце присваиваем ссылку на новый массив
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void func(ref int[] array, int value) {   
    var na = new int[value];         
    Array.Copy(array, na, value < array.Length ? value : array.Length); 
    array = na;
}
```

Но лучше будет сделать так, чтобы функция явно возвращала новый массив:

```
static int[] func(int[] array, int value) {   
    var na = new int[value];         
    Array.Copy(array, na, value < array.Length ? value : array.Length); 
    return na;
}
...
    var newarray = func(myarray, value);
    foreach(int item in newarray) Console.Write(item + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Ну зачем же за человека весь то код писать. Задача явно учебная. Но хозяин барин, конечно )